# Why do these two functions cause malfunctions in other parts of the website?

Tags: jquery

I have several jQuery functions in the "functions.php" file on my website.
I've noticed that both these two functions below, although they work properly, create malfunctions in other parts of the website. By eliminating them, however, these malfunctions disappear, although there is apparently no connection whatsoever.

For example, they cause jQuery to not be applied to other pages, or make buttons that should toggle show / hide elements not working. The code seems to me to be correct. Any suggestions?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var hieghtThreshold = $('#come-funziona').offset().top -76 -$(window).height()/3;
    var hieghtThreshold_end  = $('#come-funziona').offset().top +$('#come-funziona').height() -76 -$(window).height()/3;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= hieghtThreshold && scroll <=  hieghtThreshold_end ) {
            $('.come-funziona-lato').addClass('accendi');
            } else {
            $('.come-funziona-lato').removeClass('accendi');
            }
        });
    });
```

-

```
jQuery(function($) {
              var monthNames = ["gennaio", "febbraio", "marzo", "aprile", "maggio", "giugno", "luglio", "agosto", "settembre", "ottobre", "novembre", "dicembre"];
              var dayNames = ["domenica", "lunedì", "martedì", "mercoledì", "giovedì", "venerdì", "sabato"];
              var holidays = ["2019, 12, 8", // 8 DICEMBRE 2019
                              "2019, 12, 25", // 25 DICEMBRE 2019
                              "2019, 12, 26", // 26 DICEMBRE 2019
                              "2020, 1, 1", // CAPODANNO 2020
                              "2020, 1, 6", // EPIFANIA 2020
                              "2020, 4, 13", // PASQUETTA 2020
                              "2020, 4, 25", // 25 APRILE 2020
                              "2020, 5, 1", // 1 MAGGIO 2020
                              "2020, 6, 2", // 2 GIUGNO 2020
                              "2020, 8, 15", // 15 AGOSTO 2020
                              "2020, 11, 1", // 1 NOVEMBRE 2020
                              "2020, 12, 8", // 8 DICEMBRE 2020
                              "2020, 12, 25", // 25 DICEMBRE 2020
                              "2020, 12, 26", // 26 DICEMBRE 2020
                              "2021, 1, 1"]; // 1 GENNAIO 2021
              var endDate = "",
                noOfDaysToAdd = $(".valMixBeatVoce").html(),
                count = 0;
              var someDate = new Date(new Date().toDateString());
              var numberOfDaysToAdd = noOfDaysToAdd;
              someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate());
              while (count < noOfDaysToAdd) {
                endDate = new Date(someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 1));
                var isHoliday = holidays.find(holiday => endDate.getTime() == new Date(holiday).getTime());
                if (isHoliday) {
                  console.log('holiday, skipping');
                } else if (endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6) {
                  count++;
                }
              }
            $('#DateMixBeatVoce').html(dayNames[endDate.getDay()] + ' ' + endDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[endDate.getMonth()]);
            $('#DateMixBeatVoce2').html(dayNames[endDate.getDay()] + ' ' + endDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[endDate.getMonth()]);   
            });
```

### Update

As advised by dev4life, I uncommented line by line, and checked the browser console, as suggested by Paul T. The lines that give error are the following, but I could not understand why.

For both lines below, the console browser says, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined”

```
var hieghtThreshold = $('#come-funziona').offset().top -76 -$(window).height()/3;
```

.

```
var hieghtThreshold_end  = $('#come-funziona').offset().top +$('#come-funziona').height() -76 -$(window).height()/3;
```

And for the two lines below, he says: “Uncaught TypeError: endDate.getDay is not a function”

```
$('#DateMixBeatVoce').html(dayNames[endDate.getDay()] + ' ' + endDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[endDate.getMonth()]);
```

.

```
$('#DateMixBeatVoce2').html(dayNames[endDate.getDay()] + ' ' + endDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[endDate.getMonth()]);
```

Comment: Seems strange that you're selecting as html and treating it as an integer, `noOfDaysToAdd = $(".valMixBeatVoce").html()`. Maybe try `.text()` but I doubt this is the issue. You may also want to do `$.isNumeric(noOfDaysToAdd)` to verify.

Comment: Comment out the contents of the functions.  Then start uncommenting line by line to see what breaks the pages.

Comment: Does the browser console show any errors?

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I found the errors that the console browser tells me. Please look at the update in the post above.

Comment: It says top of undefined means the element doesn't exist during the script runtime. Turns out, a bug in JS will stop any JS code that follows. Try to test for the element existence first to ensure the stability of the code

Comment: In fact, both functions are dedicated to the home page, and the error does not appear in the browser console of the home page.
The error appears on the browser console of other pages, like the cart page, where the element to which the function refers does not exist.
Could a solution be to make the functions operating only on the home page? Maybe changing the code in some way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, to move it from the question to the answer space)*.

I'm not sure it's correct to fix it this way, but at least it works. I made the function load only on the home page.

```
jQuery(function($) {
if ($('body.page-id-5749').length > 0) {  // That's home page
    var hieghtThreshold = $('#come-funziona').offset().top -76 -$(window).height()/3;
    var hieghtThreshold_end  = $('#come-funziona').offset().top +$('#come-funziona').height() -76 -$(window).height()/3;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= hieghtThreshold && scroll <=  hieghtThreshold_end ) {
            $('.come-funziona-lato').addClass('accendi');
            } else {
            $('.come-funziona-lato').removeClass('accendi');
            }
        });
    }
    });
```